# SQL query for joining information for multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are my 3 tables :

**meetings**

meeting_id

first_user_id

second_user_id

**users**

user_id

pic_id

**pictures**

pic_id

pic_filename

**What I need is a SQL query that results in the following record :**

meeting_id

first_user_id

second_user_id

first_user_pic_filename

second_user_pic_filename

**So far this is what I was thinking :**

```
SELECT meetings.*, pics1.filename first_user_pic_filename, pics2.filename second_user_pic_filename

FROM meetings 

INNER JOIN users users1 ON meetings.first_user = user_id

INNER JOIN users users2 ON meetings.second_user = user_id

INNER JOIN pictures pics1 ON pics1.pic_id = users1.pic_id

INNER JOIN pictures pics2 ON pics2.pic_id = users2.pic_id
```

I'm not sure exactly what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I am currently getting is only a few records back, when there should be 10-15. I am wondering if there is an issue with how I am joining.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please explain why you think you are doing something wrong

Comment: Sorry, added a summary of the issue I am experiencing in terms of the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should change

```
INNER JOIN pictures pics1 ...
INNER JOIN pictures pics2 ...
```

to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN pictures pics1 ...
LEFT OUTER JOIN pictures pics2 ...
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much. I will accept as soon as it lets me. I have to admit I am not clear on why that works, as I know just about enough SQL to get me in to trouble with something like this it seems. If possible, can you specify why I'd use LEFT OUTER JOIN in this situation ?

Comment: @prototypical Because users can have no pictures. So it's left join. Otherwise with inner join you will get only users who have pictures.